# What formula do I need to add another row that is 30+ of y continously

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having with issues with making my add_withxvariable widgets loop to keep adding a new subject once monday is pressed, each beaching y + 30 so it goes down the screen.

You'll see the problem if you run the code. I'm not the best at explaining lol

also i think need if statement somewhere to stop people from spamming the monday button to keep adding fields. I want it so it's one entry at a time and the user must pressed enter in order to add another field

```
from tkinter import *

global count
count = -1





window = Tk()






def add():
  
  global count
  count = count + 1



  if count >= 1:
    return

  global subject  
  subject = Entry(window, width=5)
  subject.place(x=50, y=135)
  
  def click():
    subject_Label = Label(window, text=subject.get())
    subject_Label.place(x=50, y=135)

    


  global Subject_button
  Subject_button = Button(window, text="Enter", width=1, command=lambda: [click(), subject.place_forget(), Subject_button.place_forget()])
  Subject_button.place(x=100, y=135)
    
def add_withxvariable():
  global add_withxvariable
  
  
  new_subject = Entry(window, width=5)
  new_subject.place(x=50, y=subject.winfo_y()+30)
  
  def click():
    new_subject_Label = Label(window, text=new_subject.get())
    new_subject_Label.place(x=50, y=new_subject.winfo_y())

    


  
  new_subject_button = Button(window, text="Enter", width=1, command=lambda: [click(), new_subject.place_forget(), new_subject_button.place_forget()])
  new_subject_button.place(x=Subject_button.winfo_x(), y=Subject_button.winfo_y()+30)



def switcher():
  global count

  if count >= 1:
    add_withxvariable()


window.geometry = ("500x500")

window.configure(bg="gray")

Title = Label(window, text="SCHEDULE",font=(10)).pack(side=TOP)

Monday = Button(window, text="Monday", font=(10), command=lambda: [(add(), switcher())])
Monday.place(x=50, y=100)



window.mainloop()
```

I've made y = subjectwinfo_y() + 30 but because the value is 135 it cannot be looped to continously run the code to keep on add rows that is y + 30..

I can't figure it out and it's driving me crazy lol

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: also when i see the `global` keyword used and nested functions, this immediately tell me that `classes` should be used....

Comment: How would you import classes into it? I'm inexperienced with classes

Comment: too large to post as comment, so i have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

as per the last comment supporting the question, an example of using classes (which gives the advantage of encapsulation) is as follows:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create main window
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("My GUI")
        self.root.geometry("400x300")

        # Widgets
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=f"nothing has been said")
        self.button_01 = tk.Button(self.root, text="hello", command=self.button_click_01)
        self.button_02 = tk.Button(self.root, text="goodbye", command=self.button_click_02)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        
        # Layout
        self.label.pack()
        self.button_01.pack()
        self.button_02.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

        self.counter = 0 
        

    def button_click_01(self):
        ''' the button is clicked '''
        value = self.entry.get()
        self.label.config(text=f'hello world ! {self.counter} .. {value}')
        self.counter += 1

    def button_click_02(self):
        ''' the button is clicked '''
        self.label.config(text=f'goodbye... {self.counter}')
        self.counter += 1
        
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

# Usage
app = MyGUI()
app.start()
```

This enables you to keep everything inside the class without the need for using the `global` keyword. There are variants of the above, but this will be a good start...

You should set about fitting your existing work into this.

If you get stuck, then please ask again (in a new question).